# Unexpected token { when I require "express-fileupload"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to get file uploading to work with NodeJS running on Ubuntu, but I keep getting errors. After adding

```
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
```

the app will no longer compile. It spits out this error instead

```
2|theproje | /home/asgeir/nodejs/first_test_app/node_modules/express-fileupload/lib/index.js:5
2|theproje | const {buildOptions} = require('./utilities');
2|theproje |       ^
2|theproje |
2|theproje | SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
2|theproje |     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
2|theproje |     at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
2|theproje |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
2|theproje |     at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
2|theproje |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
2|theproje |     at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
2|theproje |     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
2|theproje |     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/asgeir/nodejs/first_test_app/server.js:2:20)
2|theproje |     at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
2|theproje |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
```

I guessed it must have been some compatibility issue between the versions, so I tried upgrading Node to the latest version. Ubuntu will only allow me to have version v4.2.6 though, so I failed to update it to a newer version.

Any help with this error, or a recommendation for a file uploading module that works with an older NodeJS version would be appreciated!

Comment: yeah, v4.2.6 probably doesn't understand that syntax, and will probably fail in may other places ... there's documentation on the nodejs site on how to get updated nodejs - which release of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: following a few links in nodejs, you come to https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md - that should get you up with the latest LTS or release version of nodejs

Comment: @JaromandaX Ubuntu version: 16.04 LTS I tried upgrading Node, but it just always gives me the old version. Just saw new comment, will read now

Comment: I'd recommend the LTS version (10.x) - in my opinion there's too many libraries that simply don't install in 12.x - mainly due to native code not compiling - because of lazy library maintainers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update to the latest (LTS) nodejs in ubuntu

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

or, the latest release

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

source: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Using `npm i express-fileupload@1.2.1` solves the issue under `Node.JS 12.x`.

Answer (score -1):

The error seems to be because [destructuring assignment was added in Node 6.0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Browser_compatibility), due to security and compatibility issues like this, you should update to at least Node 8.x, preferably to 10.x

If you really can't update you could try using [v0.2.0 of express-fileupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload/v/0.2.0) as that seems to be the last version that supports Node 4.x, just do `npm i express-fileupload@0.2.0`